# Desing pattern for designing a Java library

Tags: java, design-patterns

There is this design issue that I'm trying to figure out at work. Would appreciate some inputs.

We have a core C application that acts as an interface engine to facilitate multiple devices from talking to each other and exchanging messages in different formats. This application is installed on a server and a whole wide variety of devices can initiate communication with this server and exchange messages. Now we're trying to extend the scope of this application be providing a Web interface for a subset of operations - mostly monitoring the plethora of devices connected to the server.

The architecture that I have in mind is to write a Java library that can be used to talk to the core C application.
Then create a REST API that makes calls to this Java library. This API will be accessed by the front-end application, further up the stack.
I'm looking for suggestions on what design pattern to use for this library.
The core task that it does is monitors a whole bunch of different devices that communicate with each other.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you're going web, take some time to look into Spring-Boot.  Microservices would work great for this situation.  Plus, you can separate your web backend from the backend that implements the communications and suddenly it opens to many other applications.

Answer (score 1):

> The core task that it does is monitors a whole bunch of different devices that communicate with each other.

All you have to do is to use an `interface`!

```
interface Device { /* put methods that will be used to monitor the devices */ }

class FooDevice implements Device { /* ... */ }

class BarDevice implements Device { /* ... */ }

// ...
```

> The architecture that I have in mind is to write a Java library that can be used to talk to the core C application.

In case you didn't know, using the [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) is the <strike>easiest (and probably the only)</strike> standard way to do that.

Comment: JNI is the standard way, but not the only way to use native code from Java; you can also use, for example [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) which is supposed to be easier than JNI.

Comment: Actually, if performance matter it is better to use [JNR](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi) instead of JNA. JNR as fast as JNI, because it uses bytecode generation while JNA uses reflection. In the same time JNR as simple as JNA.